# Delete elements in an array with one value repeated

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
$elements = array(
    array("name" => "Paco", "group" => 2),
    array("name" => "Juan", "group" => 3),
    array("name" => "Marta", "group" => 2),
    array("name" => "Julia", "group" => 4),
    array("name" => "Silvia", "group" => 2)
);
```

I need to avoid repeating the group. If there are several elements with the same group, the final array must have only the first of each group:

```
$elements = array(
    array("name" => "Paco", "group" => 2),
    array("name" => "Juan", "group" => 3),
    array("name" => "Julia", "group" => 4)
);
```

Is there a better way than *foreaching* the array and processing each row? Something like GROUP BY in SQL?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I think I can't use serialize&array_unique solutions because the subarrays don't repeat (only one value in them does it), so serialize generates different strings even when "group" value is repeated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seeing as a lot of strange code has come up, some are wildly inefficient or just strange in my opinion:

```
$values = array(); 

foreach($elements as $element) { 
    if (!isset($values[$element['group']])) {
        $values[$element['group']] = $element; 
    }
}
```

And what you should have now is an array where only the FIRST occurence of a group is saved and only requires one pass, O(N). If you don't want the index to be the group id then just do:

```
$values2 = array_values($values);
```

PS. If you really dislike array_values(), then you could also do it like this (or some variation of this):

```
$values = array();
$groupkeys = array();

foreach($elements as $element) { 
    if (!isset($groupkeys[$element['group']])) {
         $values[] = $element;
         $groupkeys[$element['group']] = TRUE;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution:

```
$groups = array_map(function($x) { return $x['group']; }, array_reverse($elements));
array_values(array_combine($groups, array_reverse($elements)));
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to loop through entire array and manually remove duplicates:

```
$found = array();
foreach ($elements as $key => $element) {
    if (in_array($element['group'], $found, true)) {
        unset($elements[$key]);
    }

    $found[] = $element['group'];
}
```

In fact [`array_unique()` function](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) does the same, but on C level.

Comment: I thinsk you miss array_unique does not work with multidimension array. $elements - Is a multidimension and asker want to have a multidemnsion array to in result

Comment: `unset($element);` doesn't remove it from the array

Comment: @arnaud576875: Of course you're right. I've fixed my solution.

Comment: This is wildly inefficient, in_array is O(N) and an O(N) loop, so you end up with something like O(N^2).

Answer (score -1):

Try this, courtesy of the comments on php.net/array_unique, it makes a new array where the key is a hash of the serialized array, should prevent dupes in a multidimensional array.

```
<?php
$values = array();

foreach($elements as $element) {
    $values[md5(serialize($element))] = $element;
}

sort($values);
?>
```

Comment: ya, maybe once every 20 thousand years. Though certainly something to consider.  You could also use something like sha256 instead.

Comment: It's possible to just sort the array by group otherwise and then do another pass putting the first of every group in a "final array". Avoids expensive serialization of elements... and if not, arrays in PHP are sparse I believe, you could just use groupid as the key and do a single pass.

Comment: "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil" - Knuth

Comment: -1: This is not what OP wants (he wants only one row per group, not unique rows).